# How can i delete a file when a record is deleted from database ? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

My database registration is

```
$cover = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('images', $file);
$article->cover = $cover;
$article->save();
```

Article table connected to another table with cascade, when the record is deleted, the article record is also deleted. The file path registered in article table, but it still stands in folder. How can i delete the file, is it possible ?

**EDIT**

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('blog_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('blog_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('blogs')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

When blog record is deleted, article record also deleted. So i cant any procces in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this in your model:

```
public static function boot ()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::deleting(function ($file) {

            Storage::disk('public')->delete('images/'.$file);

    });
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not solution. Article table connected to another table with cascade. Article records deleting when the another record is deleted.

Comment: @i1919 show us your code where you deleting all stuff.

Comment: Updated my question, please check.

Comment: @i1919 Updated my answer, maybe this help you in someway.